# JPA query getResultList unmodifiable list?

Tags: java, jpa

I have started using JPA 2 / JPQL. I see a lot of examples where query.getResultList() is returned. But have never seen the resultlist marked as unmodifiable. For instance:

```
    final TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Some query", String.class); //$NON-NLS-1$
    return query.getResultList();
```

Is there any reason this should not be marked as unmodifiable, if I dont expect to change the result set returned from the database?
Any reason this could cause issues?

Comment: It already is unmodifiable from getResultList. Try adding something to the returned list and see for yourself--you'll get an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more there's no reason to mark it as unmodifiable.  If you want to change the contents of the list, feel free, it's just the results from a database.

The list in the query object has no reason to make it unmodifiable.  It's just an in memory store of what's in the database at that point so modifying this list doesn't make changes to the database unless you actually persist this new list.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, @david99world. 
So you suggest its fine for me to make it unmodifiable if I know this list should be used as read-only in my application?

Comment: I don't see any problem with you doing this, but I guess my question is why does it warrant this?  This seems just defensive programming rather than actually having a real issue with it.

Comment: Someone suggested this when they reviewed the code - since the method returns a collection that is expected to be read only.
I had encountered this blog post (http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2011/04/jpa-and-unmodifiable-collections.html)  earlier that suggested some cons of doing that. I had tried doing the unmodifiable myself but didnt see any issues. I also could not find a discussion around these lines - So just wanted to check this.